# "PEAR package PHP_Archive not installed" after upgrade php to 5.4.38 on centos6.6

Tags: php

if I havn't install php before, everything is OK.

When I upgrade php from 5.4.36 to 5.4.38, it says `PEAR package PHP_Archive not installed: generated phar will require PHP's phar extension be enabled.` and then there is no `pecl` in `bin` dir.

I have to manually install by `wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar && php go-pear.phar`, but `go-pear.phar` does not support cli param so I have to manually press `enter` to continue the pear installation.

I hope pear can be installed automatically, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

The warning about PHP_Archive can safely be ignored. If you want to get rid of it, you can install the PHP_Archive PEAR package (`pear install pear/PHP_Archive` should do the trick). The message should then disappear provided the path to PEAR's code directory is in your `include_path` (which is the case for a default installation).

The missing `pecl` command is what's really strange. Not really sure what's going on there. As a workaround and to answer your last question, there is another installer for PEAR which accepts command line options. You can grab it from https://pear.php.net/install-pear-nozlib.phar. This installer can then be used to install PEAR silently.

Comment: `Failed to download pear/PHP_Archive within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.14.0, stability "alpha", use "channel://pear.php.net/PHP_Archive-0.14.0" to install
install failed`